# Método com retorno genérico

Tags: java, método, genéricos

Como faço um método que retorne um tipo informado nos parâmetros?

```
public <E> E to(E e)
{
    return (E)obj;
}

String st = to(String);
Integer it = to(Integer);
```

Mas isso gera erro, tem outra maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito usando [`Class.cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public <E> E to(Class<E> e)
{
    return e.cast(obj);
}
```

Chama assim:

```
String st = to(String.class);
Integer it = to(Integer.class);
```

[Exemplo](http://ideone.com/oNgAvc). Lembrando sempre que seu `obj` precisa ser de um tipo compatível com a classe usada como argumento. Também é bom frisar que essa é uma operação "insegura", não mais insegura que simplesmente fazer um *cast* para o tipo que você quer:

```
public Object to() {
    return obj;
}

...

String st = (String)to();
Integer it = (Integer)to();
```

De modo que nesse caso não vejo muita vantagem nisso, mas alguém com mais experiência em Java pode conhecer algum caso de uso mais prático para esse `Class.cast`. De qualquer forma aí está, para referência...

P.S. <del>Essa solução funciona inclusive com classes cujo "nome" não seja conhecido em tempo de compilação. Isso significa que você pode, por exemplo, fazer `to(Class.forName("Foo"))` e obter uma referência do tipo `Foo`. *O problema* é que - se seu código já sabia que ia tratar de um `Foo`, era só fazer um *cast* pra `Foo`... Se não sabia, esse tipo "correto" vai acabar indo parar em uma referência de tipo mais geral...</del>

**Correção:** devido ao *type erasure*, essa solução só funciona com classes cujo tipo é conhecido em tempo de compilação, e cujo **parâmetro genérico** seja correto, i.e.:

```
Class<?> classe = Class.forName("String");
String st = to(classe);`
```

não funciona.

Comment: Tipo, tem como user esses tipos genericos em métodos, sei que na classe é assim por exemplo ArrayList<String> mas tipo, tem como fazer isso em um método tipo String a = metodo<String>(); ?

Comment: @LeonardoSnt Não, ainda que um método possa ter tipos genéricos (como esse `<E>` do seu exemplo) só se pode inferir ele a partir do parâmetro passado, não especificá-lo da forma como você quer. O que você *poderia* fazer (é feio, mas é o "normal" em Java...) é criar uma classe genérica com um método que respeita seu parâmetro, tipo: `class MinhaClasse<T>{ public T metodo() {... } }` e usá-la como `MinhaClasse<String>().metodo();` (talvez salvando uma referência pra essa instância para não ter de recriá-la a cada vez que precisar chamar o método). Mas continuo sem entender o propósito disso...

Answer (score 4):

Você tem que chamar:

```
String st = to("");
Integer it = to(0);
```

E conserta o método também:

```
public <E> E to(E e) {
    return (E)e;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/hZc5o5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gkdspbmj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Wildcard.java).

Comment: Primeiro, sua pergunta não fala nada disto. **Eu respondi o que foi perguntado**. Segundo, sem uma informação completa não posso ajudar mais que isto. Qualquer outra tentativa seria chute já que não vi o resto do seu código. Terceiro, parece que você está tentando fazer algo impossível. Só não garanto por faltar informação de todas as classes envolvidas. Mesmo que dê para fazer de alguma forma, parece ser uma grande gambiarra.

Comment: @LeonardoSnt concordo com o bigown, é sempre importante dar o máximo de **contexto** à pergunta, em especial perguntar sobre *o problema real que você está enfrentando* e não sobre [*sua tentativa de solução*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/215). Eu dei [uma resposta alternativa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56939/215) (ainda baseado na pergunta original, não no seu código do pastebin - que presumo tratar de várias classes numa mesma hierarquia), mas sinceramente não vejo que problema isso resolve que não poderia ser também resolvido com um simples *cast*...